# RadComboBox databound not working fine for RadComboBox .selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
         EmptyMessage="Choose a Department" 
         onselectedindexchanged = "ddlDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged"
         EnableLoadOnDemand="True" >
   </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

corresponding C# databound code :

```
List<MdlPurchaseinvoice> objdpt = new List<MdlPurchaseinvoice>();
ddlDepartment.DataSource = SettingManager.GetDepartmentDetails();
ddlDepartment.DataTextField = "strDepartmentName";
ddlDepartment.DataValueField = "intDepartmentId";  
ddlDepartment.DataBind();
```

now i need to programically select an item in the said combobox, for which i used

```
ddlDepartment.Selectedvalue = objpurchaseorder.intDepartmentId.ToString();
```

but unfortunately error is displayed near "Selectedvalue" as "it does not have any definition for selected value". 
How can i solve this error ??

Comment: Is this "Selectedvalue" Compiler Error.?

Comment: yes, its underlined in red(visual studio 2010)

Comment: Can you please tell me the Error Message?

Comment: Error 1 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selectedvalue' and no extension method 'Selectedvalue' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\IMS\IMS\Purchase\purchase_requisition.aspx.cs 97 27 D:\IMS\IMS\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked in Telerik site, **SelectedValue** Property Exist ,

I think you use the Wrong CASE , use **SelectedValue** instead of **Selectedvalue**

```
ddlDepartment.SelectedValue = objpurchaseorder.intDepartmentId.ToString();// New Code

ddlDepartment.Selectedvalue = objpurchaseorder.intDepartmentId.ToString();// OLd Code
```

Comment: are you using which IDE ? If you are using VS 2010 this Error wont be there